# Statically-typed dialect of Lisp with type inference, for Windows?

Tags: windows, lisp, type-inference

Is there any statically-typed dialect of Lisp that performs type inference and is compatible with Windows?

I have found CMUCL but it doesn't seem to have a Windows-compatible version.

Comment: CMUCL is a [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp) compiler, not a "statically-typed dialect of Lisp that performs type inference", though the compiler can in some circumstances do type inference (see [this](http://common-lisp.net/project/cmucl/doc/cmu-user/compiler-hint.html#toc154)). If you are looking for a functionnal language with type inference in the language specifications, you may have a look at [OCaml](http://caml.inria.fr/index.en.html), for instance.

Comment: Perhaps you want some ML with a Lispy syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org) which descends from CMUCL. It has good support for static typing through type declarations, performs plenty of type inference, and runs on Windows.

It's very much dynamic by default, though. You might be interested in [Typed Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/).

Comment: There is also a version of a more Windows compatible version of SBCL. https://github.com/akovalenko/sbcl-win32-threads

Comment: It acts funny for some reason (look at the spacing in the error messages)... I can't figure out what to do after an error: http://i.imgur.com/eDYyqbL.png Thanks though, it seems to have what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[Stalin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalin_%28scheme_implementation%29) is a free Scheme implementation doing type inference (for whole program optimization purposes) and having a [Windows port](http://code.google.com/p/stalingui/)

<sup>I confess I hate the name so much that I did not try it a lot.</sup>

[Camlp5 Scheme syntax](http://pauillac.inria.fr/~ddr/camlp5/doc/htmlc/scheme.html) is a Scheme like syntax "preprocessor" for Ocaml (so has type inference). You should be able to run it on Windows.