# Why is this an error in in SBCL?

Tags: lambda, common-lisp, sbcl

Why is this an error in SBCL? How do you call a lambda passed to your function?

```
* (defun call-foo (foo) (foo))
; in: DEFUN CALL-FOO
;     (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA CALL-FOO
;         (FOO)
;       (BLOCK CALL-FOO (FOO)))
;
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable FOO is defined but never used.

; in: DEFUN CALL-FOO
;     (FOO)
;
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: FOO
;
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     FOO
;   caught 2 STYLE-WARNING conditions

CALL-FOO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an introduction to Common Lisp:  http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

You might also want to read about [FUNCALL](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_funcal.htm#funcall).

Comment: +1 thanks for mentioning `funcall`. Does that mean `funcall` doesn't do static type-checking? (Is there any way to call lambdas while ensuring static type checking?)

Comment: @mehrdad: funcall is a function. 'functions' don't do 'static type checking'. A compiler might. But then you need to tell the compiler something about types. Are you sure you want to use Lisp?

Comment: Well, what introduced me to SBCL was [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031009), but it seems like it doesn't work the way I expected. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Mehrdad, SBCL, like any [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp) compiler, must follow the [Common Lisp standard](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/), and by this standard you must use *[funcall](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_funcal.htm)* when you pass a function as argument. Before looking for extra compiler features, such as type inference (which is not mandatory in the standard, nor even mentioned I believe), you may consider first learning the language.